loading animation (spaLoadingTemplate) disappears before request fully loaded - nuxt3
When i used:
definePageMeta({
  middleware : async () => {
    await $fetch("/posts"); // visible until the request is loaded
  }
});

The spaLoadingTemplate remains present until the request is completed

But when using:
const {data:posts} = await useAsyncData("posts",() => $fetch("/posts")) // The page opens and spaLoadingTemplate goes and the page is white until the request is completed..;

spaLoadingTemplate goes before the request completes...
How do I make spaLoadingTemplate remain present until the request finishes? Same case in middleware but using useAsyncData or something similar...
nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  devtools: { enabled: false },
  nitro: {
    static: true,
  },
  spaLoadingTemplate: true,
});


You can try for example, So you can see what I mean:
definePageMeta({
  middleware : async (to) => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
          resolve(true);
        }, 5000);
      });
  }
});


-----------------OR------------------------
const req = await useAsyncData(
  "posts",
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        resolve(true);
      }, 5000);
    })
); 


Are you trying to have this loader when initially opening your app or during a client-side navigation? Also, what do you mean by spaLoadingTemplate goes before the request completes?

when initially opening app

spaLoadingTemplate in nuxt.config.ts

spaLoadingTemplate: true Animation is activated when the website is opened

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/nuxt-config#spaloadingtemplate

Create a plugin with any name you want and make sure it has .client.ts at the end, for example any.client.ts
I tried it on ssr:false and it worked, but I don't know when on ssr:true. The method worked for me and I don't know if there are any specific problems or risks when using this method. I take no responsibility for everything, you bear full responsibility..
inside the file:
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxt) => {
  const loadingHtml = toHtml(
    `
    <!-- html code here -->
    `);

  const loadingStyle = toHtml(
`<style>
  /* style code here */
 </style>
`, "head > *");

 let loading = false;

  nuxt.hook("page:loading:start", () => {
if (!loading) {
    document.body.appendChild(loadingHtml);
    document.head.append(loadingStyle);
}
  });

  nuxt.hook("page:loading:end", () => {
if (!loading) {
    loadingHtml.remove();
    loadingStyle.remove();
 loading = true;
   }
  });


  nuxt.hook("app:error",() => {
if (!loading) {
    loadingHtml.remove();
    loadingStyle.remove();
}
  })

  function toHtml(strHtml: string, selector: string = "body > *") {
    return new DOMParser()
      .parseFromString(strHtml, "text/html")
      .querySelector(selector) as HTMLElement;
  }
});


Sources :

How to Convert a String to HTML using JavaScript

